# gcloud 403 permission errors with wrong project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I used to work at a company and had setup my gcloud previously with `gcloud init` or `gcloud auth login` (I don't recall which one). We were using google container engine (GKE).

I've since left the company and been removed from the permissions on that project.

Now today, I wanted to setup a brand new app engine for myself unrelated to the previous company.

Why is it that I cant run any commands without getting the below error? `gcloud init`, `gcloud auth login` or even `gcloud --help` or `gcloud config list` all display errors. It seems like it's trying to login to my previous company's project with `gcloud container cluster` but I'm not typing that command at all and am in a differerent zone and interested in a different project. Where is my config for gcloud getting these defaults?

Is this a case where I need to delete my `.config/gcloud` folder? Seems rather extreme of a solution just to login to a different project?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 61, in main
    sys.exit(googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main.main())
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud_main.py", line 130, in main
    gcloud_cli = CreateCLI([])
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud_main.py", line 119, in CreateCLI
    generated_cli = loader.Generate()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 329, in Generate
    cli = self.__MakeCLI(top_group)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 517, in __MakeCLI
    log.AddFileLogging(self.__logs_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 676, in AddFileLogging
    _log_manager.AddLogsDir(logs_dir=logs_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 365, in AddLogsDir
    self._CleanUpLogs(logs_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 386, in _CleanUpLogs
    self._CleanLogsDir(logs_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 412, in _CleanLogsDir
    os.remove(log_file_path)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/terence/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.07.27/19.07.37.248117.log'
```

And the log file:
`/Users/terence/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.07.27/19.07.37.248117.log`

```
2017-07-27 19:07:37,252 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'container']
2017-07-27 19:07:37,253 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'container', 'clusters']
2017-07-27 19:07:37,254 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'container', 'clusters', 'get_credentials']
2017-07-27 19:07:37,330 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials] with arguments: [--project: "REMOVED_PROJECT", --zone: "DIFFERENT_ZONE", NAME: "REMOVED_CLUSTER_NAME"]
2017-07-27 19:07:37,331 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.

2017-07-27 19:07:37,591 DEBUG    root            (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/REMOVED_PROJECT/zones/DIFFERENT_ZONE/clusters/REMOVED_CLUSTER_NAME".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 712, in Execute
    resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 871, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/container/clusters/get_credentials.py", line 69, in Run
    cluster = adapter.GetCluster(cluster_ref)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/container/api_adapter.py", line 213, in GetCluster
    raise api_error
HttpException: ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/REMOVED_PROJECT/zones/DIFFERENT_ZONE/clusters/REMOVED_CLUSTER_NAME".
2017-07-27 19:07:37,596 ERROR    root            (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/REMOVED_PROJECT/zones/DIFFERENT_ZONE/clusters/REMOVED_CLUSTER_NAME".
```

Comment: Second time I see this kind of problem on SO, puzzling, unfortunately I can't find the other question to see if it was answered.

Comment: You've created a project from the console, the project is selected in console THEN you open the shell? Try doing all this from an incognito window and see if same thing happens. Just run  gcloud on its own.

Comment: I had to delete my `.config/gcloud`. It doesn't matter if I try to create it in the shell. The point is I can't run any `gcloud` commands at all in my shell.

Comment: Did you try removing only parts of the gcloud folder that related to the old project?

Comment: @Oliver I did not, but honestly why would I go through the trouble of figuring out which files I need to delete. `gcloud` should understand that if my permissions are 403 for my default account then it should allow me to do something else like select a different account...

Comment: Oh I totally agree you should not have had to do this. It would just have been nice to know, for the situation where removing the whole folder is not practical. No sweat.

Comment: BTW you should post your comment as an answer and accept your own answer. As it stands, your issue appears unsolved on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to delete my `.config/gcloud` to make this work although I don't believe that is a good "solution".

Comment: As said above, delete the ./config/gcloud and run 'gcloud init' again. It isn't the best solution, but sometimes you just gotta nuke it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so not sure if things have changed but ran into a similar issue. Please try this before nuking your configuration.

`gcloud` supports multiple accounts and you can see what account is active by running `gcloud auth list`.

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*        Work-Email@company.com
         Personal-Email@gmail.com
```

If you are not on the correct one, you can do

```
$ gcloud config set account Personal-Email@gmail.com
```

And it'll set the correct account. Running a `gcloud auth list` again should show the ACTIVE now on your personal.

if you haven't auth'd into your personal, you'll need to login. You can run`gcloud auth login  Personal-Email@gmail.com` and follow the flow from there and then return to the above.

Make sure to set PROJECT_ID or whatever things you may need when switching.

Now from there I found it's STILL possible that you might not be auth'd correctly. I think for this, you may need to restart your terminal session or even simply doing a `source ~/.bash_profile` was sufficient. (Perhaps I needed to do this to refresh the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable but I'm not sure).

Hope this helps. Try this before nuking

Answer (score 0):

Rename / delete config/gcloud/logs folder and try  Instead of deleting .config/gcloud folder.

This Solution worked for me :)